# How can I get everything to line up in the footer?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a html and css website. In the footer I have a logo, some copyright text and some social icons. I have the logo and the copyright text were I want them, but the social icons is under the footer and doesn't want to move. I want the social icons to be inline with the logo and text.

I have tried **display: inline-text;** and it dose inline everything, but it also pushes everything to the left. That would be ok but I can't use margins or padding to counteract it. I have also tried to float the images and text which work for the logo and text, but the icons are still under the footer. Which again I can't use margins or padding to counteract it.

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
}

header {
  height: 130px;
  background-color: teal;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.logo {
  height: 130px;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(147, 233, 190);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

a {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

main {
  height: 400px;
}

.hero_img {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .500), rgba(0, 0, 0, .500)), url("https://via.placeholder.com/300x100");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.main_text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

footer {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgb(1, 108, 150);
}

.logo_div {
  float: left;
}

footer .logo {
  height: 75px;
}

.social_icon_div {
  text-align: right;
}

footer .social_icons {
  height: 75px;
}

footer p {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 57px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contanier">
  <div class="hero_img">
    <header>
      <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="logo">
    </header>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">TEST1</a>
      <a href="#">TEST2</a>
      <a href="#">TEST3</a>
      <a href="#">TEST4</a>
      <a href="#">TEST5</a>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <div class="main_text">
        <h1>Hi I am Todd</h1>
        <p>I am a web designer</p>
        <button>Hire Me</button>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div class="logo_div">
        <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        <p>Copyright© 2024 MonkeyInc All rights reserved</p>
      </div>
      <div class="social_icon_div">
        <img class="social_icons" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Social Icons">
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, you have a typo: `contanier`.

Comment: You need some dive into CSS basics. Take a look at Flexbox, that's what you need and want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you could solve this problem with a table.

Here is the changed code that I would use:

```css
    .container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
}
header {
    height: 130px;
    background-color: teal;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.logo {
    height: 130px;
}
nav {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: rgb(147, 233, 190);
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
a {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
main {
    height: 400px;
}
.hero_img {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .500), rgba(0, 0, 0, .500)), url("assents/hero_img.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.main_text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
footer {
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgb(1, 108, 150);
}
.logo_div {
    float: left;
}
footer .logo{
    height: 75px;
}
.social_icon_div {
    text-align: right;
}
footer .social_icons {
    height: 75px;
    
}
footer p {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 57px;
    padding-top: 35px;
}
table {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="contanier">
        <div class="hero_img">
            <header>
                <img class="logo" src="assents/logo.png" alt="logo">
            </header>
            <nav>
                <a href="#">TEST1</a>
                <a href="#">TEST2</a>
                <a href="#">TEST3</a>
                <a href="#">TEST4</a>
                <a href="#">TEST5</a>
            </nav>
            <main>
                <div class="main_text">
                    <h1>Hi I am Todd</h1>
                    <p>I am a web designer</p>
                    <button>Hire Me</button>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="logo_div">
                    <img class="logo" src="assents/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="copyright">
                    Copyright© 2024 MonkeyInc All rights reserved
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="social_icon_div">
                    <img class="social_icons" src="assents/social_icons.png" alt="Social Icons">
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```